# End of file error while updating product order in smart collection using shopify_api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

Setting `products` attribute in the `order` method for more than 400 products throws following error even before calling `collection.save`

```
 EOFError: end of file reached error
```

The documentation says you can send 250 positions. But the order endpoint seams to accept 300 positions successfully.

So, can we set more than 250 product ids in the order? Ir is there any limitation on that?

And what does that error actually mean?

My code:

```
    collection = ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.find(8748376382)
    collection.order(products: [9234893,3483448,8783473,"..."])
```

Comment: Could you paste the rest of the file code? This could be an issue of mismatched `end` statements.

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal If there is an issue with `end` statement, it shouldn't work properly if I send 300 product_id's right?

Comment: Yes @KirubaKaran. That bit of the question was not present when that comment was added.

Comment: I am also facing same issue but with get, will try this trick

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I think the end of file error is caused beause of some issue occuring because the query URI's length is exceeding 14000 charecters when updating 400 `products` although `PUT` request doesn't have any limit on the URI length
I just found a way to update more than 300 product by sending the product ids in the body of the put request.

[Checkout the answer by RehashWayne in Shopify Forum](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Smart-Collections-Updating-Sort-Order-on-products-not-working/m-p/311309)

Edit the file `/usr/local/bundle/gems/shopify_api-5.2.2/lib/shopify_api/resources/smart_collection.rb` (as of my gem install path) as follows

```
module ShopifyAPI
  class SmartCollection
    def order_products(ids)
      load_attributes_from_response(put(:order, nil, {products: ids}.to_json))
    end
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
sorted_ids = [12345,12346]
collection.order_products(sorted_ids)
```